# Tikz fit-library vs fill (overlaying nested node colors)

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, nesting

I am trying to figure out the best way of nesting `tikz` nodes having a different background color. I would like the "inner" nodes to "win" concerning the background color. Currently the "outer" node ("fit") always "wins". Is there maybe a better way to aproach this?

A simple example: Nesting an inner node with background color red within an outer node with background color blue:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
% \begin{tikzpicture}%
%   \node (inner) [draw] {foo-inner};%
%   \node (outer) [draw,fit=(inner)] {};%
% \end{tikzpicture}%
% \begin{tikzpicture}%
%   \node (inner) [draw,fill=red] {foo-inner};%
%   \node (outer) [draw,fit=(inner)] {};%
% \end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node (inner) [draw,fill=red] {foo-inner};%
  \node (outer) [draw,fill=blue,fit=(inner)] {};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

Comment: One way would be to add `fill opacity` as in `\node (outer) [draw,fill=blue,fit=(inner),fill opacity=0.5] {};`, or simply reverse the order.

Answer (score 14):

You can also try to send the fitting node to the `background` layer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node (inner) [draw,fill=red] {foo-inner};%
  \node (inner2) [draw,fill=green] at (2,2) {foo-inner2};%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \node (outer) [draw,fill=blue,fit=(inner) (inner2)] {};%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Note that this is more of hack:

If you reverse the order this *"appears"* (see Note below) to yield desired results:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node (inner) [draw,fill=red,fill] {foo-inner};%
  \node (outer) [draw,fill=blue,fit=(inner)] {};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node (outer) [draw,fill=blue,fit=(inner)] {};%
  \node (inner) [draw,fill=red,fill] {foo-inner};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

### Note:

As Jake correctly points out the above solution works **only** because the first `tikzpicture`.  So, just reversing the order won't work in general. But, you could repeat the node you want at the top:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node (inner) [draw,fill=red,fill] {foo-inner};%
  \node (outer) [draw,fill=blue,fit=(inner)] {};%
  \node (inner) [draw,fill=red,fill] {foo-inner};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

Comment: Hm, I think the second example only works because you have the first example in the same document. Try changing the text of the `inner` node in the second example to something longer, or removing the first `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @Jake: Thank you so much for pointing this out. [Wondering if I should delete this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/should-i-delete-answer-that-is-a-hack).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution from the `pgfmanual.pgf`:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=8mm]
    \node (root) {root}
        child { node (a) {a} }
        child { node (b) {b}
            child { node (d) {d} }
            child { node (e) {e} } }
        child { node (c) {c} };

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node[fill=red!20,inner sep=0pt,circle,fit=(root) (b) (d) (e)] {};
        \node[fill=blue!20,inner sep=0pt,circle,fit=(b) (c) (e)] {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you use many nested nodes, take a look to `pgfdeclarelayer` and `pgfsetlayers`.

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
```

This will define two additional layers and set their order.